# Joomla front page manager not working

Tags: joomla

I have 3 articles in the front page manager. However, when I change the order of these articles in the front page manager, it does not change on the actual front page of the site. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the menu item sort order method. Go in to your front page menu item, click on Parameters (Advanced) then select the primary order method you would like to use. By default it does it by article ID, you need to change it to order.